# Is it OK to Inherit from a templated smart pointers types only class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, smart-pointers

I don't want to write in every class that I use shared_ptr or unique_ptr this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> p = CreateFoo();
```

I'm using this:

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_types
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> sptr;    
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T> uptr;
};

class A: public ptr_types<A>
{
public:
    A(){}
    int m;
};
```

Then, I can do this:

```
A::sptr p(new A);
```

Is it a problem from a design point of view inheriting my classes that use smart pointers? Is there a more elegant solution?

**EDIT:**

Yes I can use:

```
auto p = std::make_shared<A>();
```

but what about if I have this:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> A::CreateA()
{
....
}

void A::Sink(std::unique_ptr<A> p)
{
...
}
```

Better to have something like that?

```
A::sptr A::CreateA()
{
...
}

void A::Sink(A::uptr p)
{
...
}
```

Maybe the question doesn't make sense.. and it's me being lazy to write the std::blabla all the time in function type returns or parameters.

Comment: what if `A` inherits from another class derived from `ptr_types` ?

Comment: Mmm that will be a problem, there will be a name collision, isn't it?

Comment: The problem is `make_shared` is more efficient than `new Blah` and you aren't using it in this solution. Maybe that can be fixed.

Comment: I know I should use make_shared but the question is not about using make_shared or new.

Comment: I think I prefer `auto p = std::make_shared<A>();`

Comment: @FrameBuffer, you can add `using typename ptr_types<A>::sptr; using typename ptr_types<A>::uptr;` to resolve the ambiguity

Comment: @JonathanWakely I don't think you need `typename`? It's not dependent.

Comment: You seems concerned about conciseness, so I suppose by "elegant" you meant "as short and efficient, without incurring issues".

Comment: I guess a (good?) solution would be to make your own namespace (which you try to emulate by inheritance),  and put there shortcuts for lengthy worded types/functions/variables. Then it's a tradeoff between importing the namespace (and including the related headers!) and using its symbols directly. But you still have to carry around template parameters (which you got rid of with your solution). There are no implicit parameters in templates yet.

Comment: Sorry, implicit parameters have nothing to do with that (and they do exist I was confused).

Comment: By "more elegant", do you mean "shorter", or "easier to understand"? Code is usually read more often than it's written, and `std::shared_ptr<A>` is more readable than `A::sptr` to anyone more familiar with the standard library than your personal conventions.

Comment: @T.C. you're right, I was being too cautious .. or just not thinking clearly :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating (smart) pointers of class shouldn't be that class responsibility. I don't think that adding such a behaviour is good idea, but if you want to do that i think your creator functions should use perfect forwarding, so you can pass parameter for constructions:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> CreateA(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Using std::make_shared (and std::make_unique if you have C++0x14) by itself is standard solution for creating cheap allocated objects. I don't think any additional solutions are needed.

Comment: 'Creating (smart) pointers of class shouldn't be that class responsibility.' - where else would you specify which pointer type and implementation to use by clients? How else would you implement a function that returns a pointer, but also retains partial ownership (e.g., memoize pattern w/o copy)?